# Why isn't the following Python script installing libraries using pip?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to automate creating a project in Django with the following script.

```
import os, sys, pip, virtualenv

directory = sys.argv[1]
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)

new_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), directory)
os.chdir(new_dir)

if not os.path.exists('venv'):
    os.makedirs('venv')

venv_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "venv")
virtualenv.create_environment(venv_dir)
activate_script = os.path.join(venv_dir, "bin", "activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_script, dict(__file__=activate_script))

pip.main(["install", "--prefix", venv_dir, "pytz"])
```

The last line installs `django`, but doesn't install `pytz`. It says that `pytz` is already installed, but when I activate the `venv`, start python from within the `venv` and `import pytz`, it cannot load it. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip.main is not executing in the context of the virtual environment, but instead it tries to install pytz in your system distribution. That's why you get the message that it is already installed. You can use subprocess.call to specify which pip to use.

```
import os, sys, virtualenv, subprocess
directory = sys.argv[1]
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)

new_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), directory)
os.chdir(new_dir)

if not os.path.exists('venv'):
    os.makedirs('venv')

venv_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "venv")
virtualenv.create_environment(venv_dir)
subprocess.call(['{}/bin/pip'.format(venv_dir), 'install', 'pytz'])
```